# Graph API Insights: /video_insights edge returns nothing for videos without crossposting functionality

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

Hi I'm new to everything,

I have an `Editor` role in a Facebook page which should give me permission to retrieve video insights from the Graph API.

Out of 25 total videos posted on that page, I can only view insights from 10 videos in Graph API, and I don't know why.

All I noticed is that all the videos whose stats I can't read don't have the crossposting functionality and their `is_crossposting_eligible` field = `false`.

But when I go to the actual facebook page all the insights for all videos are right there, but in Graph API, I can only retrieve insights for 10 out 25 posted videos.

Sorry if my question isn't professionally asked.

Comment: What permissions did you grant? Do things change, if you get your page role changed to Analyst?

Answer (score 0):

The `video_insights` edge doesn't return anything for videos which aren't crossposted videos - that edge is a new feature which applies only to cross posted videos presently

For other videos you posted to a page, you can get insights on the individual posts' `/insights` edge, and some of the metrics are specific to video posts

`post_video_avg_time_watched`, `post_video_complete_views_organic`, etc ( full list in docs here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.7/insights )

Comment: can we get the user videos views which are uploaded by user on his own profile...?

Comment: No, content posted by Users don't have Insights, only content posted by Pages